# How to navigate to specific tab in Bootstrap-vue tabs in vue routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using [Bootstrap-vue tabs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/). This is HTML for tabs:

```
<b-tabs>
  <b-tab title="Exotic Dogs" href="#dogs">
    <br>Dogs here
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="Exotic Cats"  href="#cats">
    <br>Cats here
  </b-tab>

</b-tabs>
```

Here is the route for cats:

```
{
        path: '/animals/:id#cats',
        name: 'getCats',
        component: Animals // removed from HTML to simplify
    },
```

In component code:

```
this.$router.replace({ name: 'getCats', params: { id: this.$route.params.id }})
```

This will take to:

localhost:3000/animals/234909888#cats

But  dogs tab is open (the first tab) instead of cats tab. Also refreshing browser will display blank page.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I think a far more intuitiv Structure would be `path: '/animals/cats/:id',`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding `v-model="tabIndex"` to the `<b-tabs>` tag, and use `$route.hash` to set it in `mounted()`.

```js
<b-tabs v-model="tabIndex">
  <b-tab title="Exotic Dogs" href="#dogs">
    <br>Dogs here
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="Exotic Cats"  href="#cats">
    <br>Cats here
  </b-tab>

</b-tabs>
```

```js
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      tabIndex: 0,
      tabs: ['#dogs', '#cats']
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.tabIndex = this.tabs.findIndex(tab => tab === this.$route.hash)
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Richard I tried it but does not work I get this.$el as undefined. I am using single file component.

Comment: Indeed, that is one of the most frustrating things in Vue, some properties are not available when you expect them to be. In this case, we can switch to using the `mounted()` hook - but even then `b-tabs` is not finished rendering so `querySelectorAll` cannot find the `hrefs` on the tabs. The way around that is to be explicit about the tabs in `data()`. It is a better solution anyway, as the logic is simpler.

Comment: This worked prefect for me, I was worried because the documentation it said href was deprecated.  My path was "/prefs#lt" .  Note to other devs, the "#" in the tabs array are important for the match to work ... my tabs were.
 tabs: ["#lr", "#lt", "#ts", "#cj", "#cjw", "#ps", "#bo"]

Comment: Doing the tabIndex change on mounted() doesn't work, as it takes the value from data itself. Keeping code in the beforeMount() worked for me.